# is it possible to have the same form in the DOM multiple times if I omit form and input IDs?

Tags: html, forms

I'm using Jquery Mobile and have the same form on every page. As Jquery Mobile pulls in pages into the DOM I will end up with at least 2 pages in the DOM most of the time.

Every page has a form like this:

```
<form name="login" class="logForm">
   <input type="text" name="user" value="" />
   <input type="password" name="password" value="" />
</form>
```

I would like to know, if I can omit the **ids** on the form and all its elements in order to avoid having duplicate IDs in the DOM.

**Question**
Is this possible at all or do I need to ID every element plus the form itself?

Comment: There are no `id` attributes on any of those elements... but in any case, it's invalid to have duplicate `id` values so yes, get rid of them or make them unique. You can select elements by much more than just `id`.

Comment: so they are just for selecting elements. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to have `id`s on form elements, so yeah.

Go crazy.

Comment: Thank you! Removing IDs now :-)